# To get value by its key, from other dictionary through XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I set `ObservableCollection<Employe>` as source for `ListBox.ItemsSource`, and set some `DataTemplate` for `ListBox.ItemsSource`.

XAML for template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="tmpEmploye">
    <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Gray" CornerRadius="5">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Surname}" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" 
                           FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Patronymic}" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Post}" Foreground="Gray" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" 
                       FontStyle="Italic" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>                               
</DataTemplate>
```

XAML for ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbEmployees" x:FieldModifier="internal" 
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tmpEmploye}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Result:

[image]

Look, the `Employee` class has a `Post` property, which is an index of record from `ObservableDictionary<Int64, String>` (my some class). You can see the '-1' values, but I need to get value for this key from my `ObservableDictionary<Int64, String>` object. Can I get necessary values and to display it through XAML code?

Answer (score -1):

You can write a IMultiValueConverter, and bind both the Post property and your dictionary to it.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx

Comment: role of converter is to convert from one value to another eg. bool to visibility converter. Converters are never preferred for doing some business logic operations.

Comment: @DJ Looking at what he's trying to achieve, this is not business logic, but a basic ID to Description translation. I see no fault in using a value converter.

And how about make a constructive suggestion instead of just downvote someone else's~~~